# Calling script works from terminal but not from python subprocess.call

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache, subprocess, cgi

Below is my code. It works when calling in terminal but does not work from a python 2.7 script.

```
/usr/bin/python3.5 /var/www/html/web_map/simplemap/resources/py/align_raster.py
/mnt/13aa104a-192c-43e5-95af-68aba6ac57a9/temp/85a0b2f9-c3fb-4913-9d70-a0c49f3649ba/chlor_a-modis-aqua-01_2013.tif,
/mnt/13aa104a-192c-43e5-95af-68aba6ac57a9/temp/85a0b2f9-c3fb-4913-9d70-a0c49f3649ba/chlor_a-modis-aqua-02_2013.tif,
/mnt/13aa104a-192c-43e5-95af-68aba6ac57a9/temp/85a0b2f9-c3fb-4913-9d70-a0c49f3649ba/chlor_a-modis-aqua-03_2013.tif,
/mnt/13aa104a-192c-43e5-95af-68aba6ac57a9/temp/85a0b2f9-c3fb-4913-9d70-a0c49f3649ba/chlor_a-modis-aqua-04_2013.tif,
/mnt/13aa104a-192c-43e5-95af-68aba6ac57a9/temp/85a0b2f9-c3fb-4913-9d70-a0c49f3649ba/chlor_a-modis-aqua-05_2013.tif,
/mnt/13aa104a-192c-43e5-95af-68aba6ac57a9/temp/85a0b2f9-c3fb-4913-9d70-a0c49f3649ba/chlor_a-modis-aqua-06_2013.tif,
/mnt/13aa104a-192c-43e5-95af-68aba6ac57a9/temp/85a0b2f9-c3fb-4913-9d70-a0c49f3649ba/chlor_a-modis-aqua-07_2013.tif,
/mnt/13aa104a-192c-43e5-95af-68aba6ac57a9/temp/85a0b2f9-c3fb-4913-9d70-a0c49f3649ba/chlor_a-modis-aqua-08_2013.tif,
/mnt/13aa104a-192c-43e5-95af-68aba6ac57a9/temp/85a0b2f9-c3fb-4913-9d70-a0c49f3649ba/chlor_a-modis-aqua-09_2013.tif,
/mnt/13aa104a-192c-43e5-95af-68aba6ac57a9/temp/85a0b2f9-c3fb-4913-9d70-a0c49f3649ba/chlor_a-modis-aqua-10_2013.tif,
/mnt/13aa104a-192c-43e5-95af-68aba6ac57a9/temp/85a0b2f9-c3fb-4913-9d70-a0c49f3649ba/chlor_a-modis-aqua-11_2013.tif
_aligned.tif
```

This is the output in terminal.

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

That is a QGIS python standalone script. It always shows that error but the file processes whatever is required.

This is not working.

```
cmd = '/usr/bin/python3.5 /var/www/html/web_map/simplemap/resources/py/align_raster.py {} {}'.format(
    output_files_string, output_suffix
)
print(cmd)

result = call(cmd.split(), shell=False)
```

I also tried `shell=True`,

It coulld be caused by the code dump but is there a way to trick python that the file is fine?

**Edit**: the code dump is fixed with [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/206523/segmentation-fault-upon-exit-of-qgis-map-canvas) solution.

**Edit2:** I think this issue is related with Apache CGI Python. As it fails when running from a browser only.

Comment: It looks like you're using `python3.5` not version 2.7.

Comment: That is right. What I am calling is a python 3.5 script but I am calling from 2.7 script.

Comment: @martineau is there a way to use a function from another python version instead of using `subprocess.call`?

Comment: No sure what you mean by "use a function". You can run a whole script with another version of Python by using [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) with a sequence of args specifying the Python interpreter you want to run followed by the filename of the script you want it to run, followed by the arguments you want passed to that script.

Comment: I did but it does not work.

Comment: That's not what the code in your question is doing...

Comment: based on @ajomic answer, I tried but it didn't work.

Comment: @martineau  could apache be the cause?

Comment: I suppose it could be — however it might also be due to what you're actually putting in the `cmd` string argument (which isn't clear at this point).

Comment: The string argument is shown on the first code. Argument 1: `/mnt/13aa104a-192c-43e5-95af-68aba6ac57a9/temp/85a0b2f9-c3fb-4913-9d70-a0c49f3649ba/chlor_a-modis-aqua-01_2013.tif,
/mnt/13aa104a-192c-43e5-95af-68aba6ac57a9/temp/85a0b2f9-c3fb-4913-9d70-a0c49f3649ba/chlor_a-modis-aqua-02_2013.tif...` and argument 2: `_aligned.tif`

Comment: The single `cmd` string argument should be all those file name preceded by `/usr/bin/python3.5 /var/www/html/web_map/simplemap/resources/py/align_raster.py `. If it is, then problem must be due to something else.

Comment: Yes, it is. Actually, the first code is the `print` `cmd`

Answer (score 0):

Use `subprocess` library

```python
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)
```

You can even prevent outputs to your python console, by setting

```python
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen(cmd,
                 shell=True,
                 stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL,
                 stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Comment: Your code also does not work. The later one is a python 3 code and I have python 2 code. The issue of core dump is fixed with this solution https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/206523/segmentation-fault-upon-exit-of-qgis-map-canvas